# how to use an alias name for a calculated expression in SQL

Tags: sql

I have something like this

`CASE 
   WHEN (1-(DayDiff([END_DATE],[START_DATE])*0.01)) >= 1.5 THEN 
     1.5
   WHEN (1-(DayDiff([END_DATE],[START_DATE])*0.01)) <=0 THEN 
     0
   ELSE 
     (1-(DayDiff([END_DATE],[START_DATE])*0.01)) 
END`

Can I use alias for the formula `(1-(DayDiff([END_DATE],[START_DATE])*0.01))`
instead of using it multiple times?

Also I want to make the value 0 when the formula returns `null`.

Comment: You can use only when you use dynamic query.

Comment: You can put the expression in a subquery or CTE and then use the column alias defined there.

Comment: Nope, dynamic SQL isn't required...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give an alias for the calculated field and use that alias in your outer query. For example;

```
 select 
    CASE WHEN calc_field >= 1.5 THEN 1.5
    WHEN calc_field <=0 THEN 0
    ELSE calc_field 
    END result
from (
    select (1-(DayDiff([END_DATE],[START_DATE])*0.01)) calc_field
    from table
    ) K
```